# Convert First Order Logic to Conjunctive Normal Form

Tags: logic

- Anyone who is thin, tall and energetic will be good basketball player.
- Some people are tall but not good basketball players.
- Anyone who do exercise or eating healthy food will be energetic.
- Saman is thin and tall person who do exercises.

Tasks:

1. Write the above paragraph in First OrderLogic (FOL).
2. Convert them into Conjunctive Normal Form (CNF).
3. Using the method of contradiction check whether Saman is a good basketball player. Justify your answer.

my answer for part (i)

(1) ∀x thin(x) ∧ tall(x) ∧ energetic(x) → good_basketball_player(x) 
(2) ∃x tall(x) ¬ good_basketball_player(x) 
(3) ∀x do_exercise(x) ∨ eating_healthy_food(x) → energetic(x) 
(4) thin(saman) ∧ tall(saman) ∧ do_exercise(saman)

Is it correct or not?? plese tell me the mistakes.

Comment: (A) Do your own homework. (B) This is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a logic puzzle - and not by any stretch a programming question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about logic, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Some parentheses in the first three sentences would help to make it clear which part the quantifiers apply to. You're also missing a ∧ in number 2.

(1) ∀x [thin(x) ∧ tall(x) ∧ energetic(x)] → good_basketball_player(x)

(2) ∃x [tall(x) ∧ ¬ good_basketball_player(x)]

(3) ∀x [do_exercise(x) ∨ eating_healthy_food(x)] → energetic(x)

(4) thin(saman) ∧ tall(saman) ∧ do_exercise(saman)

Comment: Thanku Upeksha.Can you convert them into Conjunctive Normal Form? If you can please give me the answer.